# My Tax Rate VBA code states overflow error when trying to calculate income tax

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

'I am unsure why the code is not functioning correctly these are global variables that can be used throughout the module1

Public taxRates As Integer
Public grossIncome As Integer

Sub Main()

Call GetGrossIncome
Call GetTaxRates
Call CalculateTax

End Sub

Function GetGrossIncome()

'User enters their gross income

grossIncome = InputBox("Please enter your gross income ")

'if an error the user program will continue as this works fine I added this just in case

On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0

'goes back to the main to execute the next line function

End Function

'This is where I am most likely getting the error from. I cannot seem to figure out why that is the case as I thought I wrote the code correctly.

Function GetTaxRates()
Select Case grossIncome

'this case is for highest tax bracket

Case Is >= 600001
    taxRates = ((19050 * 0.1) + (58349 * 0.12) + _
    (87599 * 0.22) + (149999 * 0.24) + (84999 * 0.32) + _
    (199999 * 0.35) + ((grossIncome - 600000) * 0.37))

'this case is for second highest tax bracket

Case Is >= 400001
    taxRates = ((19050 * 0.1) + (58349 * 0.12) + _
    (87599 * 0.22) + (149999 * 0.24) + (84999 * 0.32) + _
    ((grossIncome - 400000) * 0.35))

'this case is for third highest tax bracket

Case Is >= 315001
    taxRates = ((19050 * 0.1) + (58349 * 0.12) + _
    (87599 * 0.22) + (149999 * 0.24) + ((grossIncome - 315000) * 0.32))

'this case is for fourth highest tax bracket

    Case Is >= 165001
    taxRates = ((19050 * 0.1) + (58349 * 0.12) + _
    (87599 * 0.22) + ((grossIncome - 165000) * 0.24))

'this case is for fifth highest tax bracket

Case Is >= 77401
    taxRates = ((19050 * 0.1) + (58349 * 0.12) + _
    ((grossIncome - 77400) * 0.22))

'this case is for sixth highest tax bracket

Case Is >= 19051
    taxRates = ((19050 * 0.1) + ((grossIncome - 19050) * 0.12))

'this case is for lowest tax bracket

Case Else
    taxRates = (grossIncome * 0.1)

End Select

End Function

'displays message box type of income tax

Function CalculateTax()

'This displays their income tax due
MsgBox " Income Tax due for a taxable income of " & grossIncome & " is " & taxRates

End Function
```

Comment: You should use `Decimal` for all monetary values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Wikipedia:

> In computer programming, an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic
>   operation attempts to create a numeric value that is outside of the
>   range that can be represented with a given number of digits – either
>   larger than the maximum or lower than the minimum representable value.

You are defining `Public taxRates As Integer`. The type `Integer` has limits `-32,768 to 32,767`.

However, if I take this operation (I guess I would have the same issue with the others too):

```
Case Is >= 600001
    taxRates = ((19050 * 0.1) + (58349 * 0.12) + _
    (87599 * 0.22) + (149999 * 0.24) + (84999 * 0.32) + _
    (199999 * 0.35) + ((grossIncome - 600000) * 0.37))
```

... and I replace `grossIncome` with `600001` (the minimum limit to get inside), I get the value `161,378.12` which is way bigger than the top limit of `Integer`.

Hence, you get an `overflow`. Also, note that `Integer` has no decimals, whereas a `taxRates` will most probably have decimals coming out from their ratio.

Your solution is going to be to declare `Public taxRates As Double`. I also suggest you to read this [wiki-page describing all the data types and their limits](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Data_Types).

Also, `grossIncome` should be a `Decimal` (or you would have the same issue).

Comment: @Tetroy64 check my last edit, you should do the same with grossIncome for the same reason.

Comment: I did knowing that user inputs can be much higher than 32767

Comment: You should use `Decimal` for all monetary values.

Comment: @Enigmativity you're right, I've modified my answer for `grossIncome`, thanks.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - `taxRates` and constants should also be `Decimal`.